# After osm to pgsql conversion with ogr2ogr, can't add/view tables in qgis?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

I'm converting an osm .pbf file to a postgres/PostGIS database with [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html). I can view the tables in psql, but when I connect to the database in qgis,  I can't see any of the tables after connecting to the database. I'm using the standard [osmconf.ini](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/data/osmconf.ini). What am I missing here?

ogr2ogr command:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -overwrite --config OSM_CONFIG_FILE osmconf.ini -skipfailures -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=gdal_osm" osmdataset.pbf
```

In this image you can see that the tables 'multilinestrings', 'multipolygons', etc. are visible in psql, but not when viewed in qgis.

[image: ogr2ogr conversion psql tables missing in qgis]

Comment: For some reason the geometry_columns table seems to be empty.

Comment: I have no experience with ogr2ogr but I have had problems in the past with QGIS when the table did not have a serial ID as the first column in the table.

Comment: Ogr2ogr does create integer primary key columns.

Comment: geometry_columns is empty, but the same is true for other postgis databases that I have which load successfully into qgis.

Comment: Strange. I thought that QGIS is first reading the metadata table for finding which tables are spatial, name of the geometry column, geometry type, and SRID.

Comment: What version of postgis? `SELECT * FROM postgis_version();` was it installed before you issued `ogr2ogr` command?

Comment: @EvanCarroll that returns: 2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1

Comment: So then the geometry_columns is a view. and it's not out of sync -- there is nothing to keep in sync. Just checking.